# use group by clause with ols() and receive "getMember method not supported" in DolphinDB

Tags: group-by, dolphindb

I followed the groupby usage with ols() function example but got the error message: getMember method not supported.

This is the example provided by DolphinDB manual:

```
def myols(y,x) {
r=ols(y,x,true,2)
return r.Coefficient.beta join r.RegressionStat.statistics[0]
}

select myols(y,(factor1,factor2)) as `int`factor1`factor2`R2 from t group by id;
```

This is what I wrote:

```
def myols(y,x) {
r=ols(y,x,true,2)
return r.RegressionStat.statistics[1]
}
select myols(price, volume) as r2 from t1 group by date, wind_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try…catch() and return double() when the exception is thrown

```
t1 = select * from table_raw where date>2021.12.08
def myols(y,x) {
r=ols(y,x,true,2)
try {return r.RegressionStat.statistics[1]} catch(ex) {return double()}
}
select myols(price, volume) as r2 from t1 group by date, wind_code
```